# Race-condition when fetching data after connection lost websockets

Tags: reactjs, spring, websocket, stomp

I have a spring/react/redux setup with stompjs and two cases:

First case:

User1 sends data to User2. User2 loses connection. Connection is renewed User2 hits the server for the lost data with timestamp, but right after the connection is renewed and before User2 recieve the lost data User1 sends more data and User2 recieves it before he recieves the lost data that is older.

Second case:

I have chats list the most recent one is on top. It is pagination list on scroll. When user scrolls I ask server for next 10 older chats. User scrolls to bottom I send request for 10 more chats, but at the same time one of those 10 chats gets updated so my subscribe gets the chat and updates the redux store it puts the chat on top of the array, but then the request for older 10 chats also carries the chat that the subscribe just recieved.

How to handle those cases should I filter the whole array and check if the data is newer and only after I found older data to insert it and in the second case to check if chat is present in the whole array and not insert it. Is there another way to handle those cases?